# Unreachable code detected na conexão com banco

Tags: c#

Opa boa noite,

Pessoal to com um duvida certeza que é algo bobo, é que não to acostumado a usar um classe de conexão externa no desenvolvimento, tinha esse mau-habito mas agora fui usar e to encontra um Unreachable code se alguem conseguir me ajudar/explicar o porque agradeço :) Segue classe e método o erro ta no con.desconectar();:

```
public class Conexao:IDisposable
{
    private static string stringConexao = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stringConexao"].ConnectionString;

    private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(stringConexao);

    public void conectar()
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
    }

    public void desconectar()
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    public SqlConnection getCon()
    {
        return con;
    }
}

public int cadastrarAssociado (Associado assoc)
    {
        using(Conexao con = new Conexao())
        {
            using(SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand(procCadastrar, con.getCon()))
            {
                comando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cpf", assoc.Cpf);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", assoc.Nome);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rg", assoc.Rg);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_nasc", assoc.Nascimento.Date);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endereco", assoc.Endereco);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@apto", assoc.Apto);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cidade", assoc.Cidade);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@estado", assoc.Estado);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", assoc.Email);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usuario", assoc.Login);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@senha", assoc.Senha);

                try
                {
                    con.conectar();

                    return Convert.ToInt32(comando.ExecuteScalar());

                    con.desconectar();
                }
                catch (SqlException)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Só remover a linha! e sua classe conexão não foi implementado IDisposable?

Comment: Mas se eu remover a linha a conexão não vai fechar, Foi o IDisposable só pra quando terminar de usar o using tirar da memória

Comment: Se você implementar `IDisposable` e colocar o desconectar nele sim! porque está usando `using`;

Comment: Realmente agora me toquei, não falei que era algo bobo dispose ja é um close, kkkkk obrigado

Comment: coloquei na reposta!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementa a `interface` [IDisposabe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.110).aspx) como no código abaixo:

```
public class Conexao: IDisposable
{
    private static string stringConexao = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["stringConexao"].ConnectionString;

    private SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(stringConexao);

    public void conectar()
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            con.Open();
        }
    }

    public void desconectar()
    {
        if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    public SqlConnection getCon()
    {
        return con;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        desconectar();
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

Remova a linha: `con.desconectar();`, como você utilizou o [using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/yh598w02.aspx) ele vai chamar o `dispose` de forma transparente e automática de um objeto.

[C# - Por que usar using?](http://cbsa.com.br/post/c---por-que-usar-using.aspx)